# Add new project to opencl amd SDK example in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencl

I have build their solution and it works but I want to add a new project and I just can't it says

```
 Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory
```

What seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is to copy all the settings and project properties from the SDK samples and then execute. Or take a sample project and copy it to your workspace and deleted all the unnecessary files.